# Multiple image upload mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, iis-8

I'm using MVC4 on IIS8.0 to POST multiple image files to a server. This has been working for a long time, but recently the application needed to change where it saved the images. Before, I was saving to a Network location, and now I am saving directly to the same webserver where the application is running.

Now when I upload only one file gets saved. Specifically the last file in the list.

Why is this now happening? Also, I can run the application on localhost and it will save all images to the web server just fine. Once I publish and try it, it starts only taking the final image again.

From HTML:

```
<form id="inputForm" method="post" action="../images/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="uploadList">
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file4" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file5" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file6" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
</div>
```

Here are a few of the lines from web.config.

```
  <system.web>     
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

From the Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string serial)

//... Other stuff

foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        if (file.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || file.ContentType == "image/png" || file.ContentType == "image/gif")
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string result = fileName.AppendTimeStamp();
            var path = Path.Combine((Server.MapPath("~/adpear\\") + storageLoc + "\\" + theUserCompany + "\\" + serial), (serial + "_" + result));
            file.SaveAs(path);
            theSavedImageCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the path variable on the server, i think it is same for all the files. So you are only able to see the last file, as it has overridden all other files.

Comment: Looks like you are right... appendtimestamp function is doing datetime.now.tostring("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"). I'll make it truly random and try again. It makes no sense that the server would be THAT fast.

Comment: Remote debug your code or at least write the path variables to a txt file just for debugging. thats how we can know about real time values. Once done we can be sure.

Comment: I published to the server and added path to a List<string> and shot it out to the browser as JSON. Filenames are as follows. "XXXX11111_20140506101324621.jpg" ,"XXXX11111_20140506101324621.jpg", "XXXX11111_20140506101324621.jpg". Exactly the same.

Comment: Check out [jQuery file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) or it's angular variant, it takes the pain out of things like this :)

Comment: Can you try like this - `String dt = Datetime.now.tostring("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"); return dt;` and then use that string in the path

Comment: Thanks JMK I will take a look when I fix this and have the luxury of time!

Comment: I got rid of the timestamp all together and just passed in my imageCount variable. They all save perfectly now. Thanks for the help troubleshooting...fast servers be fast I guess.

Comment: Can I post the comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `path` variable on the server, i think it is same for all the files. If you have the same path variable, then all files will override one another and finally you end up with last file.

Also I would suggest you to try the following logic -

```
    var fileName = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");

    // You can change this string.format as per your requirement
    // Probably you can use Guid here with proper format.
    string result = String.Format("{0}_{1}",currentDate, fileName);
    var path = Path.Combine((Server.MapPath("~/adpear\\") + storageLoc + "\\" + theUserCompany + "\\" + serial), (serial + "_" + result));
    file.SaveAs(path);
    theSavedImageCount++;
```